# Why is my javascript function outputting duplicate letters on one keystroke?

Tags: javascript

I have a code that creates and outputs different variables based on the value of my  'truth' variable. The first rendition where truth = "name" works perfectly, but when I update truth to "email" the variable suddenly duplicates any keystroke multiple times. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
var cmd = "";
var cmd1 = "";
var truth = "name";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contactlink a").click(function(){
        $(document).keyup(function(event){
            if (truth == "name"){
                if (event.which == 8){ //backspace deletes last character of string
                    cmd = cmd.substring(0, cmd.length - 1);
                }
                else if (event.which == 13){
                    var name = cmd;
                    $("#emailcontact").typed({
                        strings:["<br/><br/>Email Address: "],
                        typeSpeed: 10,
                        showCursor: false
                    }); 
                    truth = "email";
                }
                else if ((event.which >= 65 && event.which <= 90) || event.which == 32){
                    if (cmd.length == 0){
                        cmd = cmd + String.fromCharCode(event.which);
                    }
                    else if (cmd.substring(cmd.length-1,cmd.length) == " "){
                        cmd = cmd + String.fromCharCode(event.which);
                    }
                    else{
                    cmd = cmd + String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
                            }
                        }
                        $('#namecontact').text(cmd);
                    }
                    else if (truth == "email"){
                        if (event.which == 8){ //backspace deletes last character of string
                            cmd1 = cmd1.substring(0, cmd1.length - 1);
                        }
                        else if (event.which == 13){
                            var name = cmd1;
                            $("#emailcontact").typed({
                                strings:["<br/><br/>Email Address: "],
                                typeSpeed: 10,
                                showCursor: false
                            }); 
                            var cmd2;
                        }
                        else if ((event.which >= 65 && event.which <= 90) || event.which == 32){
                            cmd1 = cmd1 + String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase();
                        }
                        $('#emailcontact').append(cmd1);
                    }                       
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: every time you click on a `$("#contactlink a")` you add yet another `$(document).keyup(function(event){`

Comment: It's almost always wrong to bind an event handler inside another event handler. Just bind the second handler at the top-level.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you're adding a new `$(document).keyup(...)` listener every time the `#contactlink a` element is clicked.

To prevent that you could do something like this:

```
 $("#contactlink a").click(function(){
    $(document).off("keyup");
    $(document).on("keyup", function(event){
    });
 });
```

What this does is to remove the previously added listener before adding it again.

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Just out of curiosity, why would the keyup function keep firing even if I only clicked #contactlink a once. Is the click stored? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: @hathair5 If you want to only respond to one keyup event after the `#contactlink a` element is clicked, you should use `.one()` instead of `.on()`. The `.on()` function sets the listener and it will fire on every keyup event.